# Azure + Private DNS + Reverse Lookup + Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to create reverse lookup (PTR) records f or private zone using Terraform in Azure? If yes, can anyone share examples? Should I be creating reverse lookup zone? I can forward lookup my internal zone (something like auto generated fgityvclopuymnv.bx.internal.cloudapp.net), but I cannot reverse lookup the IP address.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. You could set reverse DNS loopups for public IP https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/public_ip.html#reverse_fqdn

Comment: Makes no sense. There is Terraform AzureRM resource page on setting PTRs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/dns_ptr_record.html, it does not say that it is limited to Public interfaces.